# Is there a J idiom for adding to a list until a certain condition is met?

Tags: j

Imagine you're generating the Fibonacci numbers using the obvious, brute-force algorithm. If I know the number of Fibonaccis I want to generate in advance, I can do something like this using the power conjunction `^:`:

```
(, [: +/ _2&{.)^:20 i.2
```

How can I instead stop when the Fibonaccis reach some limit, say `1e6`? (I know how to do this inside a function using `while.`, but that's no fun.)

I want to stress that this is a general question about J, not a specific question about Fibonacci. Don't get too distracted by Fibonacci numbers. The heart of the question is how to keep appending to a list until some condition is met.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best answer to this is in Henry Rich's book J for C programmers. Specifically, it using the Power Conjunction `^:` . You can also use it to converge until there is no change, so that the limit would not need to be defined. Henry uses the example that:

```
2 *^:(100&>@:])^:_"0 (1 3 5 7 9 11)
128 192 160 112 144 176
```

The `^:_` Power Conjunction repeats until there is no change and the `^:(100&>@:])`  tests for the result being less than 100. If it is then `^:` is applied to `1` and the loop  `2*` is done again, if it is not less than 100 then `^:` would be applied to `0` and that results in it doing nothing and nothing changes and the loop exits. The fact that it use `"0` as the rank means that it can apply the doubling function `2*` to each of `1 3 5 7 9 11` individually.

Henry really does explain the process better than I, so here is the reference for further reading.
http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_iv_irregular_o.htm#_Toc191734389

Comment: I was aware of how to use the power conjunction with a verb and with `_`, but the idea of combining them together had not occurred to me.

Answer (score 8):

Power has also [a verb form `u^:v^:n`](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d202v.htm) where the second verb can be used as a check. Eg: double (`+:`) while (`n` is `_`) less than 100 (`100&>`):

```
+:^:(100&>)^:_ ] 1
128

+:^:(100&>)^:_ ] 3
192
```

As usual, to append to the result of power, you box the noun:

```
+:^:(100&>)^:(<_) ] 3 
3 6 12 24 48 96 192
```

Comment: "As usual, to append to the result of a power, you box the noun". I did not know this! More ad hoc polymorphism in J.

Comment: J will accept `a:` in place of `(<_)`. I don't know if this is more idiomatic or just another J mystery though.